# Limiting access to the documentation website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web, redirect, iis

I have an ASP.NET MVC website with ASP.NET Identity authentication `http://www.example.com`. I also have a documentation website `http://docs.example.com` with the product documentation.

How do I restrict the access to product documentation website, recycling the credentials of ASP.NET Identity. What options do I have? I'm using the latest IIS.

I saw that others companies display this message box:

[image]

Comment: What technology did you use to create the documentation site? There you should add authentication and connect to the same identity system. If you merely want IIS to perform authentication for you, then you have to write an IIS extension yourself, since built-in modules of IIS do not cover ASP.NET identities.

Comment: Try asking AI before asking humans. Does [my AI chat history](https://www.perplexity.ai/search/de307988-1020-407a-be44-7915e4f44235?s=u) help you?